# iOS11 Unable to change navigation bar height in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, ios11, xcode9

I am creating navigation bar programmatically in my UIViewController in viewWillAppear. After I updated my iOS to iOS 11, the height remains constant and is not changing now. I checked all answers related to it on Stack but those answers are for UIView but not for UIViewController.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];

    navBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:160.0/225 green:72.0/225 blue:178.0/225 alpha:1.0];

    [self.view addSubview:navBar];

}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is there a reason you're instantiating the navigationBar instead of putting the ViewController into a NavigationController? If you did the latter you could instantiate the NavigationController with a custom UINavigationBar class you also create which controls its own height.

Comment: Yes, because I wanted more control.

Comment: @WasimSafdar if you want to added multiple control to navigation bar you do achieve it using storyboard itself. Why are you creating navigation bar programatically.

Comment: @AshokLondhe  I am using these controls for some purpose. My app is very old and I was not able to change the colour of navigation bar using Navigation controller when I developed it. Now I cannot change the code because I needed to do lot of changes in my code that will take too much time and also may not work.